# Keyboard keys are only working as shortcuts keys on the computer

Tags: keyboard

I have a problem in Ubuntu 16.04:

The letters `d` and `f` does not work in isolation, only together. When I type them simultaneously, the letter `g` is produced.

What can this be?

**I already formatted my computer and the problem still persists.**

Comment: Sounds like your keyboard layout or language is not being interpreted correctly.

Comment: This *might* be helpful... https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04948046

Comment: @Robby1212 Doesn't work. I think it's a bug.